# Can't find out where the data is being stored

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have the oddest issue!

1. I have an MVC application and am using the default Microsoft authentication stuff.
2. I started up the application and registered a user.
3. I closed the application and found a new database had been connected (LocalDb)\v11.0.
4. I created a table called UserProfiles:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE UserProfiles
   (
       [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
       [UserId] NVARCHAR(128) NULL, 
       [Email] NCHAR(10) NULL, 
       [DateCreated] DATETIME2 NULL, 
       [LastModified] DATETIME2 NULL, 
       [FirstName] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
       [LastName] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
       CONSTRAINT [FK_UserProfiles_AspNetUsers] FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers](Id)
   )
   ```

   and copied all the columns into a class called UserProfile:

   ```
   public class UserProfile
   {
       [Key]
       [Required]
       [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
       public int Id { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
       //[Association("AspNetUser", "UserId", "UserId")] 
       public string UserId { get; set; } // Link with AspNetUsers user entry

       [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
       public string Email { get; set; }

       [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
       public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

       [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
       public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
   }
   ```
5. I set up an EFDbContext class:

   ```
   class EFDbContext : DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
   }
   ```
6. I set up a few edit pages and controllers for the new Profile functionality...
   Ultimately now when I log in as my registered user, and visit the UserProfile/Edit page, I can now fill in the information and when I hit save it calls the context.SaveChanges().
7. When I refrssh the page all the information is still there albeit the url has now got query parameters with all of my profile details in... well that's crap but I thought I must have some issue with my database and that is where the info is coming from... **BUT NO**... If I delete the query parameters and refresh the page, I am still getting information fill up my edit fields for my userprofile...

So I think, wow it worked first time. COOLBEANS! I looked at my database all excited.. and then found **NO ENTRY IN THE UserProfiles table I created?**

Then where on earth is this data being stored to be able to be re-called?!?!?!

I thought perhaps the database created was a red herring, and infact entity had cleverly set up a new table in a separate database, but my web.config states otherwise:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-James.WebUI-20131114020024.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-James.WebUI-20131114020024;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

So my question is. Where on earth is the data being stored if it's not being stored in my beautiful database?

**Extra info**

**UserProfileRepository:**

```
public class EFUserProfileRepository : IUserProfileRepository
{
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get { return context.UserProfiles; } }

    public void SaveUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile)
    {
        if (userProfile.Id == 0)
        {
            userProfile.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            userProfile.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
            context.UserProfiles.Add(userProfile);
        }
        else
        {
            UserProfile dbEntry = context.UserProfiles.Find(userProfile.Id);
            if (dbEntry != null)
            {
                dbEntry.Id = userProfile.Id;
                dbEntry.UserId = userProfile.UserId;
                dbEntry.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
                dbEntry.DateCreated = userProfile.DateCreated;
                dbEntry.Email = userProfile.Email;
                dbEntry.FirstName = userProfile.FirstName;
                dbEntry.LastName = userProfile.LastName;
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public UserProfile DeleteUserProfile(int userProfileId)
    {
        UserProfile dbEntry = context.UserProfiles.Find(userProfileId);
        if (dbEntry != null)
        {
            context.UserProfiles.Remove(dbEntry);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return dbEntry;
    }
}
```

**UserProfileController**

```
public class UserProfileController : Controller
{
    private IUserProfileRepository repository = new EFUserProfileRepository(); // Remove this when Unity implemented

    public UserProfileController(/*IUserProfileRepository repo*/)
    {
        //repository = repo;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserProfile userProfile = repository.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(uP => uP.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if(userProfile == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", userProfile);
        }
    }

    public ViewResult Edit()
    {
        UserProfile userProfile = repository.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(uP => uP.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId());
        return View(userProfile);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile userProfile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            repository.SaveUserProfile(userProfile);
            TempData["Message"] = "The Profile has been succesfully edited";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }


    public ViewResult Create()
    {
        return View("Edit", new UserProfile { UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId() });
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\James\James.WebUI\App_Data\aspnet-James.WebUI-20131114020024.mdf";Initial Catalog=aspnet-James.WebUI-20131114020024;Integrated Security=True

**-------------THE ACTUAL WEBSITE--------------**

The UserProfile/Edit page when visiting it now takes me to the URL:

```
...localhost:53417/UserProfile/Edit/4?UserId=********&Email=********&DateCreated=11%2F14%2F2013%2012%3A56%3A19&LastModified=11%2F14%2F2013%2013%3A07%3A05&FirstName=Jimmy&LastName=Trusler
```

So it's obvious details would come from here... but when I delete that set of query parameters, the page still renders the information after a refresh.

```
...localhost:53417/UserProfile/Edit
```

[image]

---

### @James : I have no idea, I'm actually feeling out of my depth now

[image]

---

### @James: Most likely coming from a cookie, but why is this happening, I have not told it to.. expicitily atleast

[image]

Comment: Well according to your connection string it's sitting in the `App_Data` folder in a DB file called `aspnet-James.WebUI-20131114020024.mdf`.

Comment: I'll remove that extra random number from that connection string and hope it then uses the database file that Microsoft authentication tables seem to be using.

Comment: So when I changed that connection string, I no longer have access to the User record I created in the first place. So I'm unsure as to why when I create records using my EF UserProfile it would end up in another table when the connection string refers to the tables that my user record is in (see image). Any ideas what i'm being a noob with?

Comment: I assume you have disconnected/reconnected the connection and refreshed the tables etc. incase it's just a bug in the editor? I would be shocked if the record didn't exist if it's populating the UI.

Comment: I just disconnected and reconnected (I had refreshed the server connections before). Argh...

Comment: Do you happen to have SQL Server Express installed on your machine?

Comment: Just whatever is built into VS2013 I think. I didn't actually install anything extra

Comment: Looking at your update, are you sure your browser isn't storing the details local storage or in a cookie? For example, if you refresh the page with developer tools open is there actually a network connection hitting the DB and pulling the details down?

Comment: @James - I've added a pic of network connections... I set up a new project without using Microsofts Authentication stuff and it works fine, so there is something to do with the authentication stuff.. :'( daymmm this is sucky.

Comment: Inspect the response on the very first request i.e. `http://localhost:53417/UserProfile/Edit` - if your DB is sending data over it would be coming down with that `GET`.

Comment: Ah step closer. so basically, my database save isn't working???... I can see the Frame request of the Network details saying that the actual url being called is the one WITHOUT parameters(ill share a screenie)... That means it must be stored in some cookie (which it says it is calling upon).... So why on earth is that all happening?!?!? I've not told it to ^_^. As you can see from my controllers and repositories etc, there's nothing weird going on there.

Comment: it's probably default behaviour of the browser you are using. I can't say for sure without seeing your full environment setup, however, rest assured your repository layer is the issue here.

Comment: Thank you so much man, legend.. can you put as an answer "It is coming from cookies (probably browser default behaviour of IE11)... The problem is with your repository" so I can give you some points... street cred etc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webpage being populated is a bit of a red herring - the real issue is your data is never actually saving into the database - your table viewer confirms that. If you inspect the network activity using developer tools for the request you will probably find no data is coming from the server.

The form information is probably being stored locally by the browser (e.g. local storage/cookies) and repopulating when you refresh the page so it *appears* as if the data is being pulled from the server - but it's not :)

Comment: The name of the connection string... was not correct to my dbcontext name. is this the possible actual issue?

Comment: Paint me embarrassed.. that was the issue all along! My connection string name did not have same as the entiy framework dbcontext class.. ahh sighhh.

Comment: @JamesT Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees :)